# How does one make a template system (like Tumblr's) in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markup, templating, tumblr, theming

I've looked at Liquid and the like, but I cannot find a way to make a "one file" template that can handle all situations. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but I will if I cannot find an existing solution.

The template system looks like this:

```
{block:Text}
    <li class="post text">
        {block:Title}
            <h3><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h3>
        {/block:Title}

        {Body}
    </li>
{/block:Text}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer I found is [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/), which allows me to pretty closely mirror the templating of Tumblr. Far out.